# How to reuse base64 bitmap images in the final SVG with fabric.js

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, fabricjs, base64url

I'm working on a web editor app that generates SVG Images.

I allow users to upload bitmap images as base64 into the editor.

The Problem is, that if a user uses an image multiple times, the SVG file size increases far too much.

With the SVG format, it's possible to reuse images (`<use href="ID">`). Is there a possibility to do this in fabric.js?

Comment: I really don't know if it is possible but I think it could be. Give it a try first then, if stuck or not working what you did, come back and answer.